# JavaScript object dimensions

Tags: javascript, json, object, multidimensional-array

I want to define a two-dimensional object, but I do not succeed.

```
var b = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8];
var a = {};
var c = ["baslik","resim","icerik","links"];

for(i=0;i<2;i++){
    for(s=0;s<4;s++){
       a[c[s]]=b[s];        
    }   
}

document.writeln(JSON.stringify(a));
```

Output:

```
{"baslik":1,"resim":2,"icerik":3,"links":4}
```

I want this output:

```
{"baslik":1,"resim":2,"icerik":3,"links":4},  
{"baslik":5,"resim":6,"icerik":7,"links":8}
```

Comment: Please format your code with proper indentation and formatting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try like this

```js
var b = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8];
var a = [];
var c = ["baslik","resim","icerik","links"];

var n= Math.floor(b.length/c.length);
var k=0;
for(var i=0;i<n;i++){
  
  var entity={};
  for(var j=0;j<c.length;j++){
    entity[c[j]]= k<b.length ? b[k++] : 0;
  }
  a.push(entity);

}
console.log(JSON.stringify(a));
```

Comment: Thanks Anik. I've been trying for 3 days

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
var a = []; //Must be a array
var b = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8];
var c = ["baslik","resim","icerik","links"];

for(i=0;i<2;i++){
    var obj = {} //Object
    for(s=0;s<4;s++){
        obj[c[s]]=b[s+4*i];       
    }

    a.push(obj)
}

document.writeln(JSON.stringify(a));
```

Comment: you output: [{"baslik":1,"resim":2,"icerik":3,"links":4},{"baslik":1,"resim":2,"icerik":3,"links":4}]

Comment: repeats output.. please help

Comment: Update `b[s]` to `b[s+i]`. Note that the values depend on the loop values you are doing

Comment: But at this time output:
 [{"baslik":1,"resim":2,"icerik":3,"links":4},{"baslik":2,"resim":3,"icerik":4,"links":5}]

all variable Unable to write...

Comment: Sorry i want to this output: [{"baslik":1,"resim":2,"icerik":3,"links":4},{"baslik":5,"resim":6,"icerik":7,"links":8}]

Comment: Update `b[s+i]` to `b[s+4*i]`

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```js
var b = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8];
var a = [];
var c = ["baslik", "resim", "icerik", "links"];

var n = c.length;

b.reduce(function(x, num, i) {

  x[c[i % n]] = num;

  if (((i + 1) % n) == 0) {
    a.push(x);
    x = {};
  }

  if ((i + 1) == b.length) return a;

  return x;

}, {})

console.log(JSON.stringify(a));
```